# change HTML class of a PHP element - Woocommerce

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Woocommerce store that is using Elementor mini cart.
I would like to add suggested products inside the mini cart, using this php code:

```
function content_below_products_minicart() {
    echo 'You may also like these products';
    echo do_shortcode('[products ids="13"]');   
};

add_action( 'woocommerce_mini_cart_contents', 'content_below_products_minicart', 10);
```

And it works fine, but unfortunately the UI is not the best.
So I would like to customize the CSS but the styles of those products are the same as the product archive, so editing that CSS code will also modify the appearance of the products in the Archive.
How can I create an HTML Class that I can edit on its own?

Comment: Have you tried the class attribute? https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-10

Comment: @7uc1f3r found it! Thanks

Comment: Okay, either you can delete your question or you can post an answer to your question yourself, so you can mark it as solved

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change CSS for that then you need to a div before and then use CSS, let say:

```
function content_below_products_minicart() {
    echo '<div class="my_mini_cart">'; // Added a class you can change with your desire
    echo 'You may also like these products';
    echo do_shortcode('[products ids="13"]');
    echo '</div>';
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_mini_cart_contents', 'content_below_products_minicart', 10);
```

Now you can create CSS like this, so every CSS code will under your **my_mini_cart** class

```
.my_mini_cart .product {font-size: 25px !important;}
```